# How do I apply DRY coding towards logging a random number generator?

Tags: c++, random

I have a random number generator that (so far) logs all occurrences of numbers 1-5. Is there any way to make this coding more efficient, so I don't have to repeat both the integers, cases, and printfs as much?

```
   #include "stdafx.h"

    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int frequency1 = 0;
        int frequency2 = 0;
        int frequency3 = 0;
        int frequency4 = 0;
        int frequency5 = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {

            int randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;

            switch (randNum) {

            case 1: ++frequency1;
                break;

            case 2: ++frequency2;
                break;

            case 3: ++frequency3;
                break;

            case 4: ++frequency4;
                break;

            case 5: ++frequency5;
                break;



            }

        }

        printf("%s%13s\n", "randNum", "Frequency");
        printf("1%13d\n", frequency1);
        printf("2%13d\n", frequency2);
        printf("3%13d\n", frequency3);
        printf("4%13d\n", frequency4);
        printf("5%13d\n", frequency5);

        cin.get();

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use an array.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const int FREQ_MAX = 5;
    int frequency[FREQ_MAX] = {0};
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
        int randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if (1 <= randNum && randNum <= FREQ_MAX) {
            ++frequency[randNum - 1];
        }
    }

    printf("%s%13s\n", "randNum", "Frequency");
    for (int i = 0; i < FREQ_MAX; i++) {
        printf("%d%13d\n", i + 1, frequency[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works great! However, I'm a novice programmer, and I don't quite understand the process being used here. Can you explain how the array is used?